# Is the .NET SDK not backwards compatible with older runtimes?

Tags: .net, wpf

We have installed .NET desktop runtime 6.0.1 on our machines. Building happens in a docker container with an image built on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022`, which was apparently updated to SDK 6.0.102.
Now our app will crash at startup saying

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

Local builds work just fine, I have SDK 6.0.101 installed.

The target framework in the project is defined as

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

so I thought it should run on any .NET 6.0, not only on 6.0.2, no matter with which SDK it's built.
According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward) it should even run on 6.1 by default, unless a different `<RollForward>` policy is defined.

What are we missing?

**Edit:**
It must be something with WPF, because console applications built on that container work just fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug in .net 6.0.2

see:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7172#issuecomment-1034105137

for a workaround you could try this:
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6663#issuecomment-1034371295

Or just use the sdk:6.0.101-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 image till a fixed version is released